# Rails - Overlapping Openlayers maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, openlayers, geospatial

I'm just experimenting with Openlayers maps on my site. The map functionality is working great, however I can't get the maps to position on my page correctly.

I need maps to be shown in my search results screen: 1 map per result. The code below is just to show a basic bootstrap card for each result. This displays fine (e.g. a card per result, one on top of the other, as per the screenshot below) until I add the map code. With the map code in, everything overlaps, as per the second screenshot.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[Screenshot of results without the map code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuzBZ.png)

[Screenshot of results with the map code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9TuH.png)

```html
      <% @locations.each do |location| %>
        
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <div id="map" class="map">
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    var map = new ol.Map({
                      target: 'map',
                      layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                          source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                      ],
                          view: new ol.View({
                            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.479642,52.641882]),
                            zoom: 10
                          })
                    });
                  </script>
                  
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            </br></br>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: P.S using the googlemaps functionality to show a map works fine in the same code above - e.g. the maps are shown in each card, with no overlapping.

Comment: This is more a html / css problem than anything else.  Your div id=map needs a closing `</div>` and maybe add `display: flow-root` to it in your css.  See if that helps.  Post your current css and the html output from your view would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That view is pure spagetti. You're missing two closing `</div>` tags and you're creating multiple elements with the same ID attribute which gives an invalid document and causes slop mode parsing. My advice is to start using a HTML validator and separate content, behavior and presentation which makes it far easier to write quality code.

When you have multiple elements with the same id attribute `document.getElementById` and `document.querySelector` will usually return the first element in the DOM but I don't believe this is actually standardized since its prohibited in the first place and the results could vary across browsers.

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="map"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When using OpenLayers (or Google Maps or Leaflet) you don't actually have to use ids for the [target map element](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html) - thats just done to create simple quickstart examples which don't really make a great starting point if you want to add multiple maps to a page since you have to jump through a bunch of hoops needlessly just to assign unique ids and then pass them to your JavaScript. Instead you can just pass any [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) object.

Now lets write some real grown up JavaScript:

```
// place this in your packs (Rails 6) or assets pipeline (older versions) 
// use 'DOMContentLoaded' if you are not using turbolinks
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.card .map');
  let maps = elements.forEach(function(element){
    new ol.Map({
      target: element,
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.479642,52.641882]),
        zoom: 10
      })
    });
  });
});
```

This isn't rocket science. We are selecting the elements when turbolinks does its page replacement magic (and on the initial page load) and then initializing a map instance for each element that matches the selector. And you're not sending the exact same JavaScript *n* number of times for each iteration of the loop like with that script tag abomination.

Use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) if you want to pass data like marker positions between Rails and your JavaScript.

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <div class="card">
     <%= content_tag :div,
         class: 'map',
         data: {
           lat: location.latitude,
           lon: location.longitude
         }
     %> 
     <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
       <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.card .map');
  let maps = elements.forEach(function(element){
    new ol.Map({
      target: element,
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        // Map now centers on right location. Magic!
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([data.lon, data.lat]),
        zoom: 10
      })
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Apologies for the ‘spaghetti‘ html - I was trying a first website during my week off and I also removed some code to make the example generic, which messed up the divs.  Appreciate the answer. I got it working, but will pick up some best ‘best practices’ from your answer, when I get back to it at the weekend. Cheers.